# Can I add AAR file from flutter build in Android Project?

Tags: android, flutter, module, aar

When I try to add the Flutter app to the Existing Android app I follow https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app. But this way needs the module folder to add to Existing App. Can I use the AAR file from the Flutter building for Android existing app? Or is there any other way to do the same?